# google sheets, search and replace for next colum

Tags: google-sheets, find-replace

I have a list of things and want to get them in two seperate colums. Can I do that by using search and replace ? or How do I do this ?
Here is an example

How it is

[image: how it is now]

How it should be

[image: how it should be]

Comment: you can select that column, go to `Data > Split text to columns > Separator > Custom > :` then press enter.